# Create In-call/double-height status bar in iOS 8?

Tags: ios

Is there a standard way to invoke a custom in-call/double-height status bar? If not, where's the best place to start in building my own functionality. I know there are a few years-old questions regarding how to do this, but there aren't any satisfying answers. Is there any new way to do this? (Possibly in iOS 8)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing in-call status bar (double height) for a custom VoIP app in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571066/showing-in-call-status-bar-double-height-for-a-custom-voip-app-in-ios)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing new here, but I'm not finding good past answers to dupe to, so...

Are you looking to test your app's layout under double-height status bar conditions (e.g. during a call or navigation)? Use the Simulator and go to Hardware → Toggle In-Call Status Bar <kbd>⌘Y</kbd> in the menu bar, just like it's always been.

Are you looking to do some background activity that causes a double-height status bar to appear? In that case, the status bar is provided by the system in response to you performing certain activities:

- Recording: Set the `UIBackgroundModes` → `audio` key in your app's Info.plist. Then, set the `AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord` or `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category on your audio session when you want to record audio.
- VoIP: Also et the `UIBackgroundModes` → `voip` key in your app's Info.plist. Then, set the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category on your audio session when you want to make a call.

The system determines what gets displayed on the status bar, and the App Store generally doesn't accept apps that use the status-bar-displaying background modes for something other than their prescribed purpose.

Comment: @rickster is there any way to display green in-call statusbar when foreground on a device?

Answer (score 0):

The red banner outside the app is created by iOS. To create the green in-call banner whilst inside the app, there is no inbuilt functionality for that, you will need to create your own.

I asked & answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584660/1372883)

> Basically iOS has no inbuilt functionality to display an in-app status
>   bar, you need to create your own. @cjensen's response led me to
>   [this](http://cyanware.com/madness/2015/05/31/pardon-the-interruption-uilocalnotification-addendum/)
>   article explaining this.
>
> If you need an in-app call status bar, you need to create it yourself
>   or use a library like KrauseFx's
>   [TSMessages](https://github.com/KrauseFx/TSMessages) to do it for you.
>   Using a `UILocalNotification` as @cjensen suggested is simply one way
>   to provide an entry point to decide *when* to create this banner.

Comment: It's better to flag this question as a duplicate of that one instead of reposting your answer.

Comment: #sigh It's better to <1000 other things> I'm sure