# iOS Change device speaker

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, avaudioplayer, speaker

I need to implement iPhone speaker (ear and bottom) change during audio call (using TwilioVideo SDK for connection)
Mine code:

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

do {
    if isSpeaker == false {
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.speaker)
        isSpeaker = true
    } else {
        try audioSession.overrideOutputAudioPort(.none)
        isSpeaker = false
    }

    try audioSession.setActive(true)
} catch {
    handleError(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

It works without any exceptions, but **don't change audio output speaker**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You should not use `AVAudioSession` APIs directly with Twilio Video. Instead, you should use the [`TVIAudioController` and set the `audioOutput` property](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.2/docs/Classes/TVIAudioController.html#//api/name/audioOutput) to one of the options enumerated in [`TVIAudioOutput`](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.2/docs/Constants/TVIAudioOutput.html).

```
TVIAudioController.sharedController().audioOutput = .TVIAudioOutputVideoChatSpeaker
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: That works well, thank you.
But is there any way to set category to audioSession inside of Twilio lib?

Comment: The four available output settings are: TVIAudioOutputVideoChatDefault, TVIAudioOutputVideoChatSpeaker, TVIAudioOutputVoiceChatDefault and TVIAudioOutputVoiceChatSpeaker.

Comment: I mean AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord category. I need to display green in-call statusBar, and according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/31704318/4899912, I need to just set this category to AVAudioSession. Setting it to sharedInstance doesn't help

Comment: Oh, the video SDK sets the category to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` automatically, it says that here: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/ios/video/releases/1.3.2/docs/Constants/TVIAudioOutput.html. That answer suggests some other settings you need to add too, like `UIBackgroundMode` set to `voip` in your info.plist.

Comment: My fault - set only 'voip', when need both 'audio' and 'voip' keys. But it's displayed as red (recording) status. Any chances to change it to green (in-call) ?

Comment: I don't know I'm afraid. [This answer seemed to claim you could get red or green](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246306/sbstatusbarcontroller-instance/7283146#7283146), hope it helps.

Comment: audioOutput is not found in 2.0.0 Version. Is it possible to call `TVIAudioController` ?

Comment: There are docs on specifying audio output in version 2 here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/ios-v2-configuring-audio-video-inputs-and-outputs#selecting-specific-audio-routes